# Callback from a deep hierarchy

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm in a bit of a mess here. Here is the hierarchy:

Activity > Pager Fragment > Pager Adapter > List Fragments > List Adapter > List items

Every time a list item is clicked, I need to receive a callback in the pager fragment. Do i need to chain everything with callback interfaces or is there a cleaner method?

Comment: Use `EventBus`Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use EventBus library it is eazy and do it in the cleanest way!
 https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus